# Access Tab Control based on Radio Button Selection

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am working in Access. I have a form that users select a "method" in the form of a radio button from a list. Depending on what they select, entry fields will populate. Recently we have moved to a tab control to store all of these fields.

My question is:

How do I make a certain tab show automatically when clicking on the corresponding radio button?

The fields on the corresponding tab populate but the form doesn't automatically switch to show that tab.

Thanks!

Here is the first case. In this case, the visible fields do populate when the corresponding radio button is selected. HOWEVER, the tab where these fields are stored does not automatically display. Just the first tab/page shows. I have to click on the correct tab/page to see the fields. I want the Tab/page to automatically display.

```
Private Sub frmMethodOptions_AfterUpdate()
Select Case Me.frmMethodOptions.Value
    Case 1
        'International Fields

        lblInternational.Visible = False
        lblBeneBankHeader.Visible = False
        Intl_BeneBankType.Visible = False
        Intl_BeneBankID.Visible = False
        Intl_BeneBankName.Visible = False
        Intl_BeneBankCode.Visible = False
        lblRecBankHeader.Visible = False
        Intl_RecBankType.Visible = False
        Intl_RecBankID.Visible = False
        Intl_RecBankName.Visible = False
        lblBeneInfoHeader.Visible = False
        Intl_BeneInfoAcctNumber.Visible = False
        Intl_BeneInfoAcctName.Visible = False
        Intl_BeneInfoChargeParty.Visible = False

        'Wire Fields

        lblWireInformation.Visible = True
        BeneABA.Visible = True
        BeneBankName.Visible = True
        BeneAcctNumber.Visible = True
        BeneAcctName.Visible = True
        RepetitiveCode.Visible = True

        'Common Fields

        OBI.Visible = True
        DebitAccount.Visible = True

        'Setting the method

        txtMethod.Value = 5
        txtMethodName = "Domestic Wire"
```

Comment: Are you running any code *when clicking on the corresponding radio button*? Where's that code? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes I have code which runs when the user clicks on the radio button of their choice. For each selection there is a case in which fields.visible = true or fields.visible = false depending on what they pick.

Comment: Great! How about you [edit] your question to include that code and tell us exactly which part isn't working?

Comment: I have added my code for the first case. All of that code works fine. I just need to know what code to add in order to get the corresponding tab to show as the tab front of the tab control when the radio button is selected.

Comment: Have you tried looking at what's available for the tab control? Explore its members in the *Object Browser* (F2) - there should be some `TabIndex` or `CurrentTab` or `Tab` property that you can set to an integer value - set it to `Me.frmMethodOptions.Value` and you're done.

Comment: I tried to set TabIndex to Me.frmMethodOptions.Value and received an error message "Invalid Property Value"

Comment: Ah, *now* we're getting somewhere! I'd put that in the question, along with the error message - the bit of code doing that assignment would be the only relevant code actually: see [mcve]. Is the tab collection 1-based? Is the `frmMethodOptions` *also* 1-based?

Comment: No I mean i literally just tried to change it given your recommendation and it did not work. i do not know what 1-based is.

Comment: Yes, and I literally mean that editing your question to ask specifically why that doesn't work would make a much better question - don't bother making "EDIT" banners, people that want to read the edit history can do that by clicking the edit timestamp. Just make your post focused about that failing instruction and the error message it raises. That way you'll have a good, useful question that other people can find when they run into the same problem.

Comment: 1-based means the collection indexes start at 1, 0-based means the collection indexes start at 0. It's completely possible that "invalid property value" means you tried giving it a 0 to refer to the first index, when the first item would be at index 1.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of leaving all tab/pages open, I simply made all other tabs invisible. For instance, if I had two tabs and clicked the international radio button, I would want only the international tab/page to show. By setting ONLY the tab you want to visible, you get all of the necessary fields to show and they are ready for user input.

```
tabMain_Intl.Visible = True
tabMain_Dom.Visible = False
```